# Highcharts & tooltip error

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The problem with getting tooltips.
You see only tooltip on the first point and the last over.

How to help output tooltip for all points on the graph?

http://jsfiddle.net/RBfwG/1/

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        xDateFormat: '<b>%H:%M</b>'
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "T",
        "data": [[1365895320000, 26], [1365895020000, 26.0625], [1365894720000, 26.0625], [1365894420000, 26.0625], [1365894120000, 26.125], [1365893820000, 26.125], [1365893520000, 26.1875], [1365893220000, 26.1875], [1365892920000, 26.25], [1365892620000, 26.25], [1365892320000, 26.3125], [1365892020000, 26.3125], [1365891720000, 26.3125], [1365891420000, 26.375], [1365891120000, 26.375], [1365890820000, 26.375], [1365890520000, 26.4375], [1365890220000, 26.5], [1365889920000, 26.5625], [1365889620000, 26.5625], [1365889320000, 26.625], [1365889020000, 26.6875], [1365888720000, 26.6875], [1365888420000, 26.75], [1365888120000, 26.8125], [1365887820000, 26.875], [1365887520000, 26.9375], [1365887220000, 27.0625], [1365886920000, 27.125], [1365886620000, 27.1875], [1365886320000, 27.25], [1365886020000, 27.1875], [1365885720000, 27.25], [1365885420000, 27.25], [1365885120000, 27.25], [1365884820000, 27.25], [1365884520000, 27.25], [1365884220000, 27.3125], [1365883920000, 27.3125], [1365883620000, 27.3125] ]
    }]
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I've never used HighCharts, but from their Docs, it looks like this should work. I think it's a problem with using the type as `datetime`, because this works: http://jsfiddle.net/RBfwG/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts expects the data to be presorted ascending on the X values.

```
   someData = [
        [1365895320000, 26],
        [1365895020000, 26.0625],
        [1365894720000, 26.0625],
        [1365894420000, 26.0625],
        [1365894120000, 26.125],
        [1365893820000, 26.125]            
    ];

    someData.sort();
```

See fixed fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RBfwG/4/).